# Python API to get block locations of files in HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, snakebite

I want to get the locations i.e., the Data Nodes where the blocks of a file are located in. I am using [snakebite](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite) to perform administrative operations like snapshot and snapdiff. I am wondering if there are APIs in snakebite or any other python APIs that will give me the block locations of files in HDFS. Getting them through command line:

```
    hdfs fsck -files -locations -blocks
```

will be my last option.